# How to fix open_basedir restriction error in shared server?

Tags: php, laravel, open-basedir, knp-snappy

I'm setting up laravel-snappy to create pdf.

My snappy config is as below

```
<?php
return array(
'pdf' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary' => base_path('vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf'),
...
```

By running **config('snappy')** inside tinker, I also get the exact required path that is within the laravel project folder

But I'm getting the following error

> local.ERROR: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s):

How can I solve this without changing the php settings?

Comment: The binary is trying to write to the `/tmp` directory without permission.

Comment: So, how can I set a tmp path within laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the package tries to write to the `/tmp` folder but is restricted through PHPs ini option [`open_basedir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir).

You can change this folder path to something within your application, maybe `storage/tmp`, with the [`setTemporaryFolder()`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/blob/6ee1d22492b194f5dc21fcca1a81a65b8c446bc9/src/PdfWrapper.php#L51) method.

```
$pdf = App::make('snappy.pdf.wrapper');
$pdf->setTemporaryFolder(storage_path('tmp'));
// ...
```